# Radio buttons on Preference Screen (with AndroidX/Jetpack)

Tags: java, android

I am developing a Preference Screen where the user should choose between 3 options.

[Android guidelines suggest to use radio buttons](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/settings/settings-guidelines#radio_button_selection_screen) but there isn't any components for this purpose.

How can I make a Preference Screen with radio buttons with titles and descriptions like this one?

[image: ;]

Comment: Why don't you use RadioButton and TextView inside a LinearLayout?

Comment: @YunusKulyyev because it would be using a full custom Fragment and not a PreferenceFragment